# Plotting every row in a List

Tags: plotting

Here is a simple question. It has been strangely difficult to find the answer in the documentations, or anywhere.

Suppose I have a list of the following form:

```
over = {{{1,2,3},{1,4,3},{1,2,9},{1,3,5}}}
```

How do I make a ListLinePlot where

A: Every row of "over" is represented by a line in the same plot, and
B: Every line has the same color (Red, say), and
C: Each line is somewhat transparent?

Note that "over" actually contains many more lines than shown here. So, the solution should not require that each row be selected manually. My overall idea is the use the transparency of the lines to indicate more likely values through time (as lines cross).

Below is an image of my attempt. For some reason the colors change.

[image]

Comment: Try using `PlotStyle -> Directive[ Orange, Opacity[0.3]]`.  In your code, you give PlotStyle a list of styles, and it cycles through them, so half the lines in your plot are orange and the other half have an opacity value.

Comment: Your definition of `over` has an extra set of list brackets. Plot its first part. `ListLinePlot[over[[1]],
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Red]]`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the two-argument form of [`Opacity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Opacity.html); that is, use `Opacity[op, col]` to have the color `col` with opacity `op`.

```
ListLinePlot[over[[1]], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Round"], Opacity[.5, Orange], 
   AbsoluteThickness[5]]]
```

[image]

```
Seedrandom[1]
data = RandomFunction[ARProcess[{.5, -.3}, .1], {1, 100}, 10];

ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5, Orange]]
```

[image]